# Step from r to epsilon contour in the Proof of Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

In the proof of Cauchy's Integral Formula, for a holomorphic function $f$ in D, we want to show that $f(w)$ for a $ w \in B_r(z_0) \subset D$, can be expressed in terms of an integral over $\partial B_r(z_0)$:

$f(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz$.

A possible first step of a proof is to set $\int_{|z-z_0|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz = \int_{|z-z_0|=\varepsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz $ for $\varepsilon >0$. However, I do not understand why this is necessary, as the latter integral's value is, too, shown to be independent of $\varepsilon$.

With regard to $\int_{|z-z_0|=\varepsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz = \int_{|z-z_0|=\varepsilon} \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} dz + \int_{|z-z_0|=\varepsilon} \frac{f(w)}{z-w} dz$ is this a necessary condition for the first of the two integrals on the right side of the equation to be zero? If so, why? Should not the difference quotient be holomorphic in $B_\varepsilon(z_0)$ as well as in $B_r(z_0)$ (and thus the integral be equal to zero regardless)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the integral $\displaystyle\int_{|z-w|=\varepsilon} \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} dz$? It is not zero but its limit when $\epsilon \to 0$ is $0$. It follows from the fact that $f$ is holomorphic in $D$, so $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$ is bounded near $w$.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t know weather the difference quotient is holomorphic in $a \in B_r(z_0)$. All we know, since $f$ is holomorphic, that the difference quotient is continuous in $a$. But since $B_r(z_0) \backslash \{ a \}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and there the difference quotient is holomorphic, Cauchy’s theorem applies. We are allowed to continuously deform the integration path without changing the integral’s value. Thus we can look at the limit, which yields the desired result.